# redirecting https://domain.com to https://www.domain.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've recently moved my site to HTTPS and im trying to force all http traffic to https and also to the www. version

i.e forcing
https://domain.com
to
https://www.domain.com

I have this in my htaccess and all http to https works, apart from the redirect from https://domain.com to https://www.domain.com

What am i doing wrong?

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an `OR` condition here:

```
RewriteEngine  on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked! Many thanks. I will accept your answer shortly (when it allows me)

Comment: i have problem.

when i visit www.domain.com of my site it now redirects to https://www.www.domain.com (notice the 2 www. parts)

help?

Comment: its ok i fixed i needed tot add the www.domain to the RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE] part - i was using HTTP_HOST instead - all resolved

Comment: @anubhava Hi, this is not working for the case of https => "https:/www."
all Other rewrites are fine. any solutions?

Comment: Sorry for the noob question, but where should I add it, if I have my site hosted on EC2 and registrar as Namecheap.

Comment: This can be added in Apache config or .htaccess but I am not sure about `Namecheap`

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine  on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

with the above rule https://example.com was not redirecting to https://www.example.com.
For that to happen I have added  the following rule too in the apache ssl vhost block

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.exmple.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks @sandeep krishna, it did not work for me before I added this also to the domain.com-le-ssl.conf that letsencrypt creates.