# Redirect from sub.domain.co.id to https://sub.domain.co.id

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

Good day. I have a website called with `sub.domain.co.id` and now I want to redirect it to `https://sub.domain.co.id`.

I'm using codeigniter and this what i change in my `.htaccess`

Before .htaccess look like this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

then I change it to ref([redirecting https://domain.com to https://www.domain.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798138/redirecting-https-domain-com-to-https-www-domain-com))

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http://. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://sub.domain.co.id%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

but no help. the URL still use `http`. How can i achieve that?

Comment: %{HTTP_HOST} does not contain http ,but just your domain name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this and see. (index.php will removed too)

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|image|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.co.id [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sub.domain.co.id/$1 [L,R=301]
```

> didn't test. 95% Sure. Not the 100%

Comment: @YVS1102 check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34634798/how-to-redirect-https-sitename-com-to-https-www-sitename-com?rq=1